# Markdown filter, how to add HTML attributes?

Tags: templating, css

What's a good way to add attributes (classes etc.) to the HTML elements returned from the `markdown` filter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what I currently do to add a class `Bibliography` to all generated `<ul>` tags from my `articleBibliography` field. Because there's never other content in this field, I'm save to replace them all.

```
{{ entry.articleBibliography|markdown|replace({'<ul>': '<ul class="Bibliography">'})|raw }}
```

--

**Update:**
You can also use the awesome Retcon plugin for this, it’s using DomDocument internally so the result should be more reliable.

```
{{ entry.articleBibliography|markdown|retconAttr('ul', {'class': 'Bibliography'}) }}
```

Comment: How can I add a class to an anchor? This works, but I obviously don't want to hardcode `href` and `title`. Any ideas?
```
{{ block.text|markdown|replace({'<a href="http://example.com" title="example.com">': '<a href="http://example.com" class="my-class" title="example.com">'})|raw }}
```

Comment: @AndreaDeMers please see my update to the answer

Answer (score 2):

You could put the class on the parent element, and then target `.Bibliography > ul` in your css.